# How to make an autoscrolling page effective

Tags: php, mysql

Am gonna try to make this short.  So I tried to make a page auto scroll with new contents but I encounted a problem trying to make the newly updated contents effective like the others.
Here is my code:

```js
           goNextConnection();
function goNextConnection() {
     var recent = 1;
     var scrollNote = $('.scrollNote').hide();
    $('#nextConn').click(function() {
        recent++;
        var username = $(this).attr('name');
        $('.scrollNote').show();
      $.post("connautoscroll.php", {recent: recent, username: username}, function(data) {
        if(data.trim().length == 0){
            $(".scrollNote").text("No more records!");
            $('#nextConn').prop("disabled", true);
        }
            $('.connNet section:last').after(data);
         // $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#nextConn").offset().top}, 800);
          $('.scrollNote').hide();
      });
      return false;
    });
}
```

Ok. this actually auto updates the page with new content when I click on a button. But here is what's making me crazy.
I happen to code the page updater like below but when I want to make a comment it appends the  new text, saves it on the database but on reloading the page it doesn't show the comments on the database.

```js
if( isset($_POST['recent']) && isset($_POST['username']) )
{
    $recent = $_POST['recent'];
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $item_per_page = "3";
    $position = (($recent - 1) * $item_per_page);

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM connection ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ds', $position, $item_per_page);
    $stmt->execute();
    $connMessages =$stmt->get_result();
  while($run_post = $connMessages->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  {
    $post_id  = $run_post['id'];
    $name     = $run_post['name'];
    $text     = $run_post['about'];
    $text     = $run_post['about'];
    $text     = $run_post['about'];
    $folder   = $run_post['directory'];
    $user     = $run_post['username'];
    $date     = $run_post['date'];
    $src      = $folder.$name;
    $time     = $run_post['time'];
    $datetime = $date.$time;

      $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE username = ?");
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
      $stmt->execute();
      $get_query =$stmt->get_result();
         $run_pic2 = $get_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
         $imgName = $run_pic2['imagename'];
         $imgDir  = $run_pic2['content'];
         $src2    = $imgDir.$imgName;
    if($get_query)
    {
      $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 16 DAY) ");
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $post_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $chatMsg =$stmt->get_result();

    while($getChat2 = $chatMsg->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
         $sender  = $getChat2['username'];
         $comment = $getChat2['comment'];
         $time2   = $getChat2['time'];
         $date2   = $getChat2['date'];
         $timeAgo = timeAgo($datetime);
 echo <<<END
   <section class='offers'>
        <div id='name'> $user &nbsp;|&nbsp; $timeAgo&nbsp;at&nbsp;$time
        <div class='disImg'>
           <img src=' $src2 ' class='connDisImg' alt='poster image' >
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id='telWhat'> $text </div>
        <div id='what'><img class='whatImg' alt='Image' src=' $src '></div>
        <div class='commentDiv'>
           <div class='group commentName'><b>$sender</b>-<em>$comment</em></div>
        </div>
          <input type='text' username=' $username ' post_id=' $post_id ' class='tellWhat' name='comment' placeholder='What&rsquo;d you think?'>
    </section>
END;
    }
    }else{
      echo "Error encounted";
   }
```

Please a quick help will be really appreciated. Thanks though.

Comment: First thing you might want to do is look at how to clean up the code a little, Its hard to read and should be separated to make coding for YOU easier as well as the people trying to help. Secondly do you want an auto scrolling page or to display data from database after the ajax request?

Comment: It's like I have want to display posts but those posts have space for comments. And I limit the display as 3 posts before its auto scrolls. So when they auto scroll the comments have a little prob. They get saved on the database (MySQL)  and also appends to the comment div but when I reload the page. It gets blank.